# count a very complex select mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very complex select that union 3 tables to show customer's last activities.

so:

```
select c.data, p.user, concat(c.user, ' buy your product') as logs from sell c inner join posts p on c.foto = p.id where p.user = ?
union all
select f.data, c.user, concat(c.user, ' asked you a question') as logs from questions f inner join cadastro c ON f.user = c.id where f.nick = ?
union all
select l.data, l.user, concat(l.user, ' like your product') as logs from likes l inner join posts p on l.post = p.id where p.user = ?
order by data desc
```

well, **each of this tables has a row called SEEN**. it is a varchar set with 0 or 1 (0 the user has not seen the message, 1 the user has already seen it).

What I want to add in this query is something to count the rows where seen = 0.

I want to show: **YOU HAVE 4 new alerts**.

select count(*) will not work and will not count right (the seen set to 1).

**What can I do to count all this selects where seen = 0?**

Comment: what is the name of field that has datatype varchar ? and add some sample input data to question.

Comment: oh, it is PHP $stmt->bind_param('sss', $user, $userid, $user);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select a.*, SUM(IF(a.seen='0', 1, 0)) as 'unseen_count' FROM (
    select c.data, p.user, concat(c.user, ' buy your product') as logs, seen from sell c inner join posts p on c.foto = p.id where p.user = ?
    union all
    select f.data, c.user, concat(c.user, ' asked you a question') as logs, seen from questions f inner join cadastro c ON f.user = c.id where f.nick = ?
    union all
    select l.data, l.user, concat(l.user, ' like your product') as logs, seen from likes l inner join posts p on l.post = p.id where p.user = ?
) as a
order by data desc
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?
union all

Comment: @Livia, did you replace the `?` marks with user/nick of the user you are running the query for?

Comment: yeah! it is dinamic in PHP $stmt->bind_param('sss', $user, $userid, $user);

Comment: @Livia, I'd suggest you run the query in a console like phpMyAdmin or SQLyog after replacing the params with actual values, once perfected then move to PHP

Comment: I try it too. if I use select c.data, count(p.user)... for example it will group by user isn't it? there is a way to group by p.user WITH data DESC? to show more recent news first? if this count works with data desc I think it is nice for me!

Comment: `COUNT` is an aggregate function for counting, not for latest/recent records

Comment: sorry! your query works! I haven't seen that 'as logs, SEEN from'... sorry! the problem is it only returns 1 result, and I had 7! what is wrong?

Comment: @Livia, do you have multiple users and want results for all of those? if yes then add ` GROUP BY 2 ` before `ORDER BY data DESC`. The problem is using `SUM` function without `GROUP BY` because I thought the results are for only one user

Comment: yes! I add group by 2, and it not worked, but after that I put group by 1 and it works nice!! thank you very much, you know what you are doing! thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90783/discussion-between-mynawaz-and-livia).